# XSL Grouping by Sections

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

Using XSL 1.0, I am trying to get the data between two "Section" elements.  I have no trouble getting just the "Heading" information alone, but I'd also like to know what Section that falls between since they are not siblings.  That's where I get screwed up.

I have searched the web and this forum for various solutions, mostly trying to generate a key and using grouping, but I have been unsuccessful in getting anything that works.  Sometimes it's a "whitespace expected" error or nothing at all.

**INPUT:**

```
<Root>
  <Content>
    <Paragraph Type="New Section">
      <Text>Section A</Text>
    </Paragraph>
    <Paragraph Type="Stuff">
      <Text>Random information 1</Text>
    </Paragraph>
    <Paragraph Type="Heading">
      <Text>Important information 1</Text>
    </Paragraph>
    <Paragraph Type="Stuff">
      <Text>Random information 2</Text>
    </Paragraph>
    <Paragraph Type="Heading">
      <Text>Important information 2</Text>
    </Paragraph>
    <Paragraph Type="End Of Section">
      <Text>End of Section A</Text>
    </Paragraph>
    <Paragraph Type="New Section">
      <Text>Section B</Text>
    </Paragraph>
    <Paragraph Type="Stuff">
      <Text>Random information 3</Text>
    </Paragraph>
    <Paragraph Type="Heading">
      <Text>Important information 3</Text>
    </Paragraph>
    <Paragraph Type="Stuff">
      <Text>Random information 4</Text>
    </Paragraph>
    <Paragraph Type="Heading">
      <Text>Important information 4</Text>
    </Paragraph>
    <Paragraph Type="End Of Section">
      <Text>End of Section B</Text>
    </Paragraph>
  </Content>
</Root>
```

**DESIRED OUTPUT:**

```
"Important information 1"
"Section A"
"Important information 2"
"Section A"
"Important information 3"
"Section B"
"Important information 4"
"Section B"
```

As I mentioned, using a choose and when test against Paragraph/@Type = "Heading" I am able to get the "Important information" text, but I cannot figure out how to tell between which Sections they fall.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I cannot figure out how to tell between which Sections they fall.

If you restate the problem as "which section was the last one to *start* prior to the current heading", then it becomes fairly trivial:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:template match="/Root">
    <xsl:for-each select="Content/Paragraph[@Type='Heading']">
        <xsl:value-of select="Text"/>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="preceding-sibling::Paragraph[@Type='New Section'][1]/Text"/>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>      
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: The [1] is the important part, it gets the closest one, otherwise it seems like preceding-sibling returns the first one.

Comment: Brilliant and so much simpler than what I was doing.  This worked great!  Thank you.

Comment: @WilliamWalseth Actually, `preceding-sibling` selects **all** of them. But, in XSLT 1.0, `xsl:value-of` returns only the first one, in document order.

Comment: Thanks michael. Seems weird that adding [1] indicates the first preceding, and not the first in the document.  I see that it works, just not sure I understand why.

Comment: @WilliamWalseth It's because `preceding-sibling` is a reverse axis: http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#predicates Note that this affects only predicates that are part of a location step.

Comment: Michael, you really know this stuff.  Cheers